# How to get Material CSS Chips data to PHP?

Tags: php, tags, materialize

I'm trying to get data of materialize chips tag from a form but I don't know how to get data from Materialize CSS chips/tags.

My objective is to create a single field that can input unlimited number of values, which are the names, and send the data to php.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<form>
  Leader:<br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Name"><br>

  Enter Name:<br>
      <div class="chips chips-placeholder">
         <input class="custom-class">
      </div>

</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
  $('.chips').chips();

  $('.chips-placeholder').chips({
    placeholder: 'Enter a Name',
    secondaryPlaceholder: '+Name',
  });
```

Is there any other possible way besides using Materialize? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would setup some events for when adding/removing chips from your element, and then send off that data straight away via ajax.

```
$('.chips').chips({
    placeholder: 'Enter a Name',
    secondaryPlaceholder: '+Name',
    onChipAdd: (event, chip) => {
        AddThis(JSON.stringify(event[0].M_Chips.chipsData));
    },
    onChipDelete: (event, chip) => {
        // The deletion equivelant
    },
});

function AddThis(data){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/add-name-via-ajax-post.php",
        data: { data: data },
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Successfully sent the new chip data!");
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("Error occurred whilst sending chip data!");
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this is a viable option for you.